# List only files and directory names from subprocess ls -l

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen, ls

In python subprocess using Popen or check_output, I need to list files and directories in a given source directory. But I can only use the command **ls -l**.

Sample code

```
cmd = ["ls", "-l", source]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
exitcode = proc.returncode

if exitcode != 0:
    raise SystemError("Exitcode '{}', stderr: '{}', stdout: '{}'  for command: '{}'".format(
        exitcode, stderr, stdout, cmd))
```

From above **proc**, by using grep or any other way, can I get only a list of files and directory names inside source directory without other information?

Comment: what is `source`?

Comment: @C.Nivs source is the parent directory in which we run ls -l to list all the files and directories within it

Comment: What's the context for this? Generally speaking, parsing `ls` is an antipattern, considered malpractice even in bash -- see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy context is remote client API is not supporting anything other than 'ls'

Comment: Is that at the protocol layer or the display layer? If the protocol is SFTP, f/e, the `ls` command in a SFTP client masks an unambiguous API; by implementing that API natively in Python, you avoid the issues associated with `ls`. It's worth knowing the actual wire protocol in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using subprocess please try:

```
[x.split(' ')[-1] for x in stdout.decode().split('\n')[1:-1]]
```

Obviously this is a pretty "hacky" way of doing this. Instead I can suggest the standard library [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

```
import glob
glob.glob(source + '/*')
```

returns a list of all file/directory names in source.

Edit:

```
cmd = ["ls", source]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
exitcode = proc.returncode
stdout.decode("utf-8").split('\n')[:-1]
```

Should also do it. `-l` option is not necessary here.

Comment: Why use `glob` when you've got `os.scandir()` in Python 3 (which is much *faster* than `ls` on large directories), and `os.readdir()` across all available versions (which isn't prone to all the misbehavior `ls` is -- `touch $'foo\nbar'` to create a filename any `ls`-based code will mishandle).

Comment: Definitely. I prefer glob only for its simpler syntax. You are welcome to add to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the output of `ls` is a [bad idea for a few reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If your file name has a trailing space, then `ls` will display it as `'trailing space '` and if you try to `open("'trailing space '")` it won't work. Also file names can contain newlines.

Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) instead:

```
from pathlib import Path
source = Path("/path/to/some/directory")
[x.name for x in source.iterdir()]
# ['a_file', 'some_other_file.txt', 'a_directory']
```

Answer (score 1):

As Charles Duffy mentioned, you can use os. Like this.

```
import os
directory=#wherever you want to search
files_and_directories=os.listdir(directory)
Out: ['Directories and file names in a list']
```